# Preventing re-use of jsessionid

Tags: struts, websphere-6.1, jsessionid

How I can prevent reuse of jsessionid, if some body copies url that appends jsessionid example www.example.com/user/feedback;jsessionid=sdfererefjjefeife33f:1 on other browser or a new tab in same browser.

Application is build on struts 1.1 running over websphere 6.1

Please Help

Answer (score 1):

You can disable URL rewriting in Websphere Application 6.1 cf. http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/uprs_rsession_manager.html .

Answer (score 1):

WebSphere Application Server does not normally enforce any authorization of HTTP Session access. Any party with a valid session identifier can access any session. While session identifiers aren't likely to be guessable, it may be possible to obtain session identifiers through other means. To reduce the risk of this form of attack, you should consider enabling session security. This setting is configured at

> server > server name > web container > session management

Check the box labeled security integration. Once this is done, WebSphere Application Server will track what user (as determined by the LTPA credential that they present) owns what session, and will ensure that only that user can access that session.

You have to use the authentication and authorization mechanisms provided by WebSphere Application Server in order to make this work. In other words you will have to enable application security and make use of [JavaEE security roles](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncav.html).